# Catch LogCat programmatically or export it to file?

Tags: android

I want to filter a logcat

```
String myCommand="logcat -f /sdcard/output.txt"; //no filters, keep writing  
myCommand="logcat -d -f /sdcard/output.txt"; //no filters, just a dump
```

Working fine for me but not for mytag .

I am also using the code:

```
String myCommand="logcat myTag *:S"; //the equivalent of logcat -s myTag  
myCommand="logcat -s myTag:D";   
myCommand="logcat -s myTag:E myTag2:D";  
myCommand="logcat myTag:E myTag2:D";
```

But it returns empty file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mylog.log"); 
filename.createNewFile(); 
String cmd = "logcat -d -f"+filename.getAbsolutePath();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

it works for me. but for all logcat output not for special tag(mytag).

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 17):

```
try {
   File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/gphoto4.html"); 
        filename.createNewFile(); 
        String cmd = "logcat -d -f "+filename.getAbsolutePath();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

also use

```
String cmd = "logcat -v time -r 100 -f <filename> [TAG]:I [MyApp]:D *:S";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);


-v -> Sets the output format for log messages.
-r -> for specifying the size of file.
-f -> file to which you want to write the logs.
[TAG] -> Tag of your application's log.
[MyApp] -> Your application name.
```

Comment: See [logcat command-line tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) for further logcat executable arguments

Answer (score 3):

```
public class LogTest extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
try {
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

  StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    log.append(line);
  }
  TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  tv.setText(log.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
}
}
}
```

also you need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

referenced [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically)

Answer (score 2):

I have created a class for saveing logcat to file, check this:

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * This singleton class is for debug purposes only. Use it to log your selected classes into file. <br> Needed permissions:
 * READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_LOGS" <br><br>Example usage:<br> <code> FileLogHelper.getInstance().addLogTag(TAG);</code>
 * <p/>
 * Created by bendaf on 2016-04-28 
 */
public class FileLogHelper{
    private static final String cmdBegin = "logcat -f ";
    private static final boolean shouldLog = true; //TODO: set to false in final version of the app
    private static final String TAG = "FileLogHelper";

    private String logFileAbsolutePath;
    private String cmdEnd = " *:F";
    private boolean isLogStarted = false;
    private static FileLogHelper mInstance;

    private FileLogHelper(){}

    public static FileLogHelper getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new FileLogHelper();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void initLog(){
        if(!isLogStarted && shouldLog){
            SimpleDateFormat dF = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd_HH_mm''ss", Locale.getDefault());
            String fileName = "logcat_" + dF.format(new Date()) + ".txt";
            File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/logcat/");
            if(outputFile.mkdirs() || outputFile.isDirectory()){
                logFileAbsolutePath = outputFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
                startLog();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startLog(){
        if(shouldLog){
            try{
                File prevLogFile = new File(logFileAbsolutePath);
                prevLogFile.delete();
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdBegin + logFileAbsolutePath + cmdEnd);
                isLogStarted = true;
            }catch(IOException ignored){
                Log.e(TAG, "initLogCat: failed");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a new tag to file log.
     *
     * @param tag      The android {@link Log} tag, which should be logged into the file.
     * @param priority The priority which should be logged into the file. Can be V, D, I, W, E, F
     *
     * @see <a href="http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput">Filtering Log Output</a>
     */
    public void addLogTag(String tag, String priority){
        String newEntry = " " + tag + ":" + priority;
        if(!cmdEnd.contains(newEntry)){
            cmdEnd = newEntry + cmdEnd;
            if(isLogStarted){
                startLog();
            }else{
                initLog();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a new tag to file log with default priority, which is Verbose.
     *
     * @param tag The android {@link Log} tag, which should be logged into the file.
     */
    public void addLogTag(String tag){
        addLogTag(tag, "V");
    }
}
```

Call the `FileLogHelper.getInstance().addLogTag(<YOUR_TAG>);` function in your onCreate() for example and the folder will be placed the default external storage, which is `/storage/emulated/0/` on the most of the phones.

Please let me know if you find any bug in the code!

Comment: Just a note - you shouldn't use a java singleton in an android environment. It's an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the note! Can you help me than, how would you create a logger which stays consistent accross de app lifecycle?

Comment: Dependency Injection, like dagger. Create an application singleton that each activity can reference and use. That way it's a single object who's lifecycle is attached to the application.

Comment: @LEO I think using third-party unnecessary low performance huge libraries like Dagger and others, which make no difference overall and are just for one's personal taste and personal comfort (and no offense mostly created for amateurs ), is way more  "anti-pattern" than a simple little singleton class. from https://google.github.io/dagger/ : `Dagger is a fully static, compile-time dependency injection framework for both Java and Android. It is an adaptation of an earlier version created by Square and now maintained by Google.`

Comment: creating file...but not writing log

Comment: @Manoj Behera Are you sure that you are logging with the specified <LOG_TAG> to logcat?

Comment: @bendaf : I found `logcat` folder but can't find `logcat_` file. Can you please update for same.

Comment: @MehulKabaria the output file is created only when the log started, so most probably you did not log anything with <YOUR_TAG>. Search in your logcat for the tag and don't forget to call 'FileLogHelper.getInstance().addLogTag(<YOUR_TAG>);' also!

Comment: @MDP calling dependency injection 'low performance' and 'created for amateurs' shows a huge lack of knowledge. That's utterly misleading - you should go back to the basics and learn solid principles.

Comment: @NickCardoso Yes that comment is for 4 years ago when I was an amateur myself

Answer (score 1):

Some phone can't write to external directory. So we have to write to android cache directory

```
public static void writeLogToFile(Context context) {    
    String fileName = "logcat.txt";
    File file= new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(),fileName);
    if(!file.exists())
         file.createNewFile();
    String command = "logcat -f "+file.getAbsolutePath();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
}
```

Above method will write all logs into the file. Also please add below permissions in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOVEMBER 2023**
The given answers are outdated in terms of saving a file to some space. So I give you the solution in which I catch a logcat and write its content to `.txt` file in the location with access granted by user.

There is an Activity with two buttons. First one runs intent to get from user persistable permission to location where a file will be saved by app. Obtained location path is saved in `SharedPreferences`.
Second button saves logcat content to a file. It will be writing a content until activity is not destroyed.

Code below:

```
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContent {
                Column {
                    Button(onClick = {
                        openDocumentTree()
                    }) {
                        Text("Grant access to location!")
                    }
                    Button(onClick = {
                        val path = getPathFromSharedPref()
                        if (path.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Grant access to location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        } else {
                            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                saveLogcatToFile()
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Launch Logcat!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        private fun openDocumentTree() {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
    
            openDocumentTreeLauncher.launch(intent)
        }
    
        private val openDocumentTreeLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
                    val takeFlags = result.data?.flags!! and (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                    val path = result.data!!.data!!
                    contentResolver?.takePersistableUriPermission(path, takeFlags)
                    savePathInSharedPref(path.toString())
                }
            }
    
        private fun savePathInSharedPref(path: String) {
            val editor = getSharedPreferences("default_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            editor.putString("PREFS_PATH", path)
            editor.apply()
        }
    
        private fun getPathFromSharedPref(): String? {
            val prefs = getSharedPreferences("default_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
            return prefs.getString("PREFS_PATH", "")
        }
    
        private fun saveLogcatToFile() {
            try {
                //Create file in given location
                val path = getPathFromSharedPref()
                val pickedDocumentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, Uri.parse(path))
                val newFile = pickedDocumentFile!!.createFile("text/plain", "logcat.txt")
                val out = contentResolver.openOutputStream(newFile!!.uri)
    
                // Run logcat command to get the logcat output
                val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat")
                val bufferedReader = process.inputStream.bufferedReader()
    
                // Read each line of logcat output and write it to the file
                bufferedReader.forEachLine { line ->
                    out!!.write(line.toByteArray())
                    out.write('\n'.code.toByte().toInt())
                }
    
                // Close the writer
                out!!.close()
    
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void printLog()

{

      String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "myandroidapp.log";

      String command = "logcat -f "+ filename + " -v time *:V";

      try{
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      }
      catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```