# Is there a log broadcast in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm writting an app and there are a lot of `LOG.d()` statments to check the behavior of my code.

Now I want to write the result of all this `LOG.d()` statements in an listview to see them on my device when they appear.

Is there something like an log broadcast witch I can receive in my activity or do I have to add the logic for my listview log to all the places where `LOG.d()` is called again?

Or is there maybe an other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [Process](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html) to execute the `logcat` command on the device itself, and stream its output.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -<flags>");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Amit_android's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807689/catch-logcat-programmatically-or-export-it-to-file).

You can read the generated file and display it in your app.

Comment: I recommend you to execute the "logcat -c" command before start writting the logcat to the file so you you can have just your app's logs. Remmeber to add the required permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />