# How to execute ADB commands programmatically in Java on Mac OS for Android device

Tags: java, android, adb, appium, appium-android

everybody!
I'm trying to write listener for my testing framework using Appium, java, TestNG for Android application on real device.
I want to use some ADB commands through my tests, for example take screenshot, record video, get logcat file, e.t.c.

So I have:
Mac OS
Android device Xiaomi, with Android version 7.0
ADB
ANdroid SDK
java

If I use commands in Terminal: adb exec-out screencap -p > /Users/dmytro/Documents/other/1.png  - screenshot successfully saved in appropriate folder. And other commands work fine manually typed in terminal and in terminal of my IntelijIDEA as well.

If I use the same command programmatically by using Runtime class:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(adb exec-out screencap -p > /Users/dmytro/Documents/other/1.png"); // Save screenshot to Mac machine
```

or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb logcat > /Users/dmytromynziak/Documents/other/log.txt"); //Save logical file

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("db exec-out screencap -p > /sdcard/1.png"); // Save screenshot to scared of android device
```

It doesn't work, screenshot is not saved to Mac machine and even can't find on android device.

No any error I received, looks like everything works. see screenshot from debug mode.[image: screenShot from debug mode]

Actually, some adb commands worked fine on WIndows OS, but on Mac it don't.

Help me execute ADB commands in java code please.

Comment: I'have tried to execute another command by using shell in script:  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell screencap -p sdcard/sc1.png"). and it works! but screen saved into android device, so I need to pull it. So I think problem is that I tried to use commands in my terminal, but programmatically I  stay in android device, so need to use shell script

Comment: Do you get any output, if you do `adb devices` from your Java code?

Comment: @Domestus yes, it shows list of devices, so I think problem in executed commands

Answer (score 2):

The adb commands are succeeding, but not redirected to a file as expected. With Java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, the `>` for redirect won't work. Explanation for this can be found from this StackOverflow question: [Runtime's exec() method is not redirecting the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238714/runtimes-exec-method-is-not-redirecting-the-output)

`adb logcat` itself also has `-f` flag, which tells the process to write into a file, as described in this discussion: [Catch LogCat programmatically or export it to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807689/catch-logcat-programmatically-or-export-it-to-file)